# Всем привет. Подскажите плиз как решить задачку

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив объектов

```
[{title: 'Test', name: 'Stas', surname: 'Petrov'}, {title: 'Test', country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow'}]
```

На выходе должен получиться один объект который будет объединен по ключу title

```
{title: 'Test', name: 'Stas', surname: 'Petrov', country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow'}
```

Comment: посмотри `groupBy` в Underscore.js

Comment: Могут ли в исходном массиве объектов быть объекты с разным значением title? Если да, их нужно игнорировать? Или на выходе всё же должен быть новый массив объектов, объединённых по title?

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название плиз

Answer (score 7):

```js
const data = [{title: 'Test', name: 'Stas', surname: 'Petrov'}, {title: 'Test', country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow'}]
console.log(data.reduce((a,b)=>({...a,...b}),{}))
```

С группировкой по title:

```js
const data = [{title: 'Test', name: 'Stas', surname: 'Petrov'}, {title: 'Test2',a:2}, {title: 'Test', country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow'}]

console.log(data.reduce((acc,el)=>({...acc,[el.title]:{...acc[el.title],...el}}),{}))
```

Comment: В первом примере, если title разный -- всё равно 1 объект будет

Answer (score 4):

```js
const d = [{title: 'Test', name: 'Stas', surname: 'Petrov'}, {title: 'Test', country: 'Russia', city: 'Moscow'}];

const o = {};

d.forEach(n => {
  Object.assign(o, n);
});

console.log(o);
```

Comment: `Object.assign(...d)` или `Object.assign({}, ...d)` если нужен новый объект