# Как сгрупировать данные внутри массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста как преобразовать массив объектов.

Входящие данные

```
const input = [
  {
    "id": 12255 ,
    "title": "Test" ,
    "total": 100 ,
    "performed": 0 ,
  } ,
  {
    "id": 68779 ,
    "title": "Test" ,
    "cents": 942 ,
    "currency": "USD" ,
    "stage": "expired" ,
    "strategy": "result" ,
  } ,
  {
    "id": 12772 ,
    "title": "Test1" ,
    "total": 200 ,
    "performed": 5 ,
  } ,
  {
    "id": 68889 ,
    "title": "Test1" ,
    "cents": 942 ,
    "currency": "EUR" ,
    "stage": "expired" ,
    "strategy": "result" ,
  } ,
  {
    "id": 16722 ,
    "title": "Test2" ,
    "total": 100 ,
    "performed": 12 ,
    "level": 2 ,
  } ,
];
```

То что должно получиться на выходе

```
const output = [
  {
    "id": 68779 ,
    "title": "Test" ,
    "total": 100 ,
    "performed": 0 ,
    "cents": 942 ,
    "currency": "USD" ,
    "stage": "expired" ,
    "strategy": "result"
  } ,
  {
    "id": 68889 ,
    "title": "Test1" ,
    "total": 200 ,
    "performed": 5 ,
    "cents": 942 ,
    "currency": "EUR" ,
    "stage": "expired" ,
    "strategy": "result" ,
  } ,
  {
    "id": 16722 ,
    "title": "Test2" ,
    "total": 100 ,
    "performed": 12 ,
    "level": 2 ,
  } ,
];
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171921/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83/1171926#1171926

Answer (score 0):

Решение вашей проблемы если вручную и прям на js такое надо сделать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

В общем надо реализовать метод groupby вручную как по ссылке выше или воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками